# stop traces in swc-library (actionscript3)

Tags: actionscript-3, trace, swc

There are a lot of traces embedded in a swc-library I'm using in flash-builder.
Can I get rid of them without touching its code? How?

Thanks

Comment: no: unless you edit the swc source and recompile, no AFAIK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [stripper](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/) tool from Joa Ebert [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/) framework :

```
stripper -i my-swc-library.swc
```

> ```
> Stripper
> ```
>
> This tool removes all debug
>   information from a SWF file. It is a
>   type-safe removal keeping
>   side-effects. This means a loop like
>   this
>           while(iter.hasNext) { trace(iter.next()) }
>           Would be rewritten like
>           while(iter.hasNext) { iter.next() }
>           Stripper removes also all debug releated bytecode.
>           Example:
>         stripper -i input.swf -o output.swf         stripper -i
>   inputAndOutput.swc

Answer (score 0):

in Flash Builder under project properties: `omit-trace-statements` set to true.

then it should skip all traces.

Comment: omit-trace-statements set to true has [known issues](http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/how-omit-trace-statements-works-or-does-not/), so it's best to use the Apparat framework.

Comment: omit-trace-statements will turn off your traces as well, not only those from the verbatim swc.